# Laravel Soft Delete with transaction management for the cascaded deletion

Tags: laravel

Scenario: 
         Student -> parent,
         Child Class for Student
           Parent:   Student
           Child:        Marks
                         Address
           Grand Child     Primary Address
                           Secondary Address

```
   We are using the Cascade Soft-Delete for the above scenario with the code below :
```

Here there are multiple deletions happening ,need suggestions to know if we have to add the transaction management for the cascaded deletion.

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

 class Student extends Model
  {
   use SoftDeletes;

   protected static function boot()
   {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function ($student) {
        foreach ([
            'address',
            'mark'
        ] as $relation) {
            foreach ($student->{$relation} as $item) {
                $item->delete();
            }
        }
    });
  }

 public function address()
   {
    return $this->hasMany(StudentAddress::class, 'student');
    }

  public function mark()
   {
    return $this->hasMany(Marks::class, 'mark_detail');
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding Transaction in Laravel check following code

```
\DB::transaction(function () {
      Your queried goes here
});
```

Or

```
DB::beginTransaction();
     Your queried goes here
DB::commit();
```

Comment: We want to know whether  to have a transaction management in the scenario which we have explained